# Perturbation theory - integrals over different wavefunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

I am reading a research paper on how to calculate g-tensors* computationally (*Correlated four-component EPR g-tensors for doublet molecules*).
In the theory section, they write "[...]from (quasi-)degenerate perturbation theory one gets an expression for the ﬁrst order energy corrections":
$$\begin{aligned}
E_{i j}^{(1)} &=\left.\sum_{k=x, y, z} \frac{\partial E_{i j}}{\partial B_{k}}\right|_{\mathbf{B}=0} B_{k} \\
&=\left.\sum_{k=x, y, z}\left\langle\phi_{i}\left|\frac{\partial \hat{H}^{(B)}}{\partial B_{k}}\right| \phi_{j}\right\rangle\right|_{\mathbf{B}=0} B_{k}
\end{aligned}
$$
Where $B_k$ is a component of a B-field (a parameter). It looks like they made a Taylor expansion in the first step to get the first-order energy correction, but I cannot see how they obtained the last term. It resembles what could be obtained from the Hellmann-Feynman theorem, except $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$ are not necessarily the same wavefunctions.
Can someone see how this expression is obtained?

*The g-tensor is a $3\times3$ matrix that couples an external magnetic field, $\mathbf{B}$ to the electron spin, $\mathbf{\hat{S}}$ in a molecule or atom, giving the spin Hamiltonian: $\hat{H}=\mathbf{B\cdot g \cdot \hat{S}}$. Note that the unperturbed Hamiltonian giving the $\phi$-wavefunctions is the unperturbed Dirac-Hamiltonian. The perturbation is a uniform external field described by $\hat{H}^{(B)}=c \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} \cdot \hat{\vec{A}}$ where $\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{i}=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbf{0}_{2} & \sigma_{i} \\
\sigma_{i} & \mathbf{0}_{2}
\end{array}\right)$, $\hat{\vec{A}}$ a vector potential and $\mathbf{\sigma_i}$ the Pauli spin matrices.

Comment: presumably $E_{ij}=\langle \phi_i \vert \hat H\vert \phi_j\rangle$?

Comment: Could you please define the object you're talking about? What is $B_k$ what is the form of the Hamiltonian, what is the $g$ tensor?

Comment: Which research paper?

Comment: Icv, I edited the post. Qmechanic, the research paper is also stated in the first line of the post.

Comment: @JKalle this question could be interesting but as of now it is impossible to answer. You mentioned perturbation theory so there must be an unperturbed Hamiltonian and a perturbation. Your Hamiltonian has a single term, (which can actually be trivially diagonalized), so what's up? Moreover I assume your $H$ stands for $H=\sum_{i,j} S_i B_j g^{i,j}$ ?

Comment: I thought I could be brief, but I see that I haven't provided enough information. Also, I think I confused the matter more by stating that Hamiltonian. The actual perturbative Hamiltonian used in the program is $c \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} \cdot \hat{\vec{A}}$ (from the Dirac equation - the calculations are based on relativistic theory). I kept the question short in an intend to avoid confusion.
The reason why I stated the spin Hamiltonian $\hat{H}=\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{g} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{S}}$ was to give an idea of what the g-tensor is.